# MVC writing DB query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am trying to query DB to get less results.
But I am not sure how it works.
This is how Default scaffolding for complete list looks like

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    return View(db.Activity());
}
```

This is how I think it should work.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Activity> model = new List<Activity>();
    var query1 = model.Select(p => new Activity()
    {
        ParentId = "SR_438846"
    });
    return View(query1);
}
```

View Receives

```
@model IEnumerable<DashBoard.Models.Activity>
```

I want for view to get queried list of things. Not sure how IEnumerable changes things. Reading about it didn't help.
How a simple query from the list would look like? 
If db. thing already resists.
Tnx

This is how Working Project works

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Activity> result =   db.Activity.Where(act => act.ParentId == "438846").ToList();
    return View(result);
}
```

Thanks again!!!

Comment: Yes I used similar tutorial to create full scaffolding but there is so much data it errors out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume you have set up a DbContext that contains a DbSet called "Activities" (see [Getting started using Entity Framework with MVC](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)).

Then you can write queries using [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx), for example to select all Activities with a certain Parent ID:

```
IEnumerable<Activity> result = _dbContext.Activities.Where(act => act.ParentId == "SR_438846")
```

Comment: Thank you. Not really familiar with how fancy data management works

Comment: Good solution man :D

Comment: It Worked thank you very much dude. Didn't error out or anything got full results.